# Forward SMTP trafic through OpenVPN

Tags: iptables, postfix, smtp, openvpn, email-server

Hi guys I need your help with the follwing topic:

I want to run a mail server at home. Therefore I have established an OpenVPN connection between my home network (Site A) and my VPS(Site B), which works so far.

I have already forwarded the incoming traffic from port 25 to the mail server via iptables. Requests are correctly forwarded to the mail server at home. I have implemented the whole thing with the following firewall rules (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is my VPS's public IP):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -d XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.6
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -d 10.8.0.6 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 25 -d 10.8.0.6 -j ACCEPT
```

However, I still have problems to realize the outgoing requests from (site A) using the public IP address of my VPS (site B). Can anyone give me a hint on how the iptables rule should look like to forward the SMTP traffic through my VPS’s public IP?

(OS is Ubuntu 20.04 and mail server software is postfix.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

of course, it will use the source public ip of site A because you didn't apply any source NAT on Site A to use vpn interface IP address

Comment: Can you please tell me what this rule must look like?